# something funny with embedded hsql

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb, dbvisualizer

i'm just curious about something.I'm using hsql in myproject (embedded of course).At some time i felt the need to visualize what hibernate was generating.I took a free copy of dbvisualizer. here is the hsqljdbc.properties

> jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb;create=true
>    hibernate hbm2ddl.auto=create

i downloaded the hsql 1.8.0_10. i did all the required procedure.i could connect and see the tables but after that changes made to the table don't seem be willing to show up.then i've tried to delete the db generate a new one but still.You got any idea in this?

I usually Derby but i've realized lately that it's not that precise about relationship management.I use mysql for the moment which is not good for development so i want to know if i forgot to do something or it's just meant to behave that way.Thanks for reading this

Comment: I had the same behavior with the embedded HSQLDB in the JBoss 5.0 server. EJB3 where working without any erros, but the DB was always empty. Switched to Derby for now and it's working fine.

Comment: mmmh man.unique on field doesn't seem to work in Derby for me.That's one of the reason why i switch it to hsql.Besides its syntax is like mysql one

Comment: So... did my answer work out for you? Consider providing feedback how should I know if I need to improve on my answer. Or if you yourself found a viable solution please post it

Comment: sorry for the late response.I've been using show_sql=true from the beginning but you know going trough all that readings especially when you are under pressure is a bit tedious.it helps to have a visual checking for apparent bugs or problem before digging more into it by reading the hibernate statements. at least that's what i believe or should i say what will work for me.thanks for the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using HSQLDB for development and testing is discussed in detail in the new Guide.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_app_dev_testing

HSQLDB uses a write delay mechanism by default and changes are flushed to disk after 10 seconds in version 1.8.x or 0.5 sec in version 2.0 and later.

You can force the database to shutdown and write all the changes when the last connection is closed with this URL:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb;shutdown=true
```

With HSQLDB 2.x you can use the write_delay property to force each commit to write to disk immediately:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb;hsqldb.write_delay=false
```

Version 2.2.9 and later persist the latest changes when the last connection is closed, so it may not be necessary to use `hsqldb.write_delay=false` for tests that close the connections.

With HSQLDB 1.8, you need to run an SQL command at the beginnig to do this:

SET WRITE_DELAY FALSE

Comment: thanks mate it all makes sense now. next time i will use version 2.0 and see how it goes

Comment: The latest version is currently 2.2.9. Always try the latest.

Comment: does anyone know if setting the write delay makes any difference for `MEMORY TABLES` ? or just for `CACHED` ?

Comment: Write delay is for writing the changes to the .log file and applies to both MEMORY and CACHED tables.

Answer (score 1):

By default, HSQLDB keeps table contents in memory until the database is shut down: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch05.html#N10DD6

Depending on your needs (eg, working in a development environment) this may be sufficient. For production, however, I'd rather use a DBMS that writes each change to disk in multiple places (which for my means Oracle, although MySQL probably works just as well).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just set the `show_sql` property to true if you want to see what hibernate does?